# CSHTML not rendering under mod_mono/mono3.2.5

Tags: linux, mono, apache2, razor-2, mod-mono

**Background:**

I currently have a working ASP.NET4.0 + Razor2.0(view engine only, no MVC) + mod_mono + Apache + mono3.0.4 + Ubuntu12.10 on a cloud server provider. I found another service provider which is more cost-effective than my current one.

**The Issue:**

This server is running on Ubuntu13.04 and was able to compile Mono 3.2.5(the latest release on Mono site). I configured it almost identical to my other server and made a simple CSHTML page which works on my MSVS2010; a simple page with layout. I uploaded everything to the directory and when I tried to open the page, instead of being rendered, the server only let me download the whole cshtml file.

I added these lines in mod_mono.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_mono.c>
        MonoAutoApplication enabled
        MonoServerPath /usr/bin/mod-mono-server4
</IfModule>

AddType application/x-asp-net .cshtml
```

Then on my virtual hosting file for Apache2, I added these lines to let Mono handle everything:

```
<Location /mono>
    SetHandler mono-ctrl
        Order deny,allow
        allow from all
</Location>
```

My configurations are identical to my previous server which is working properly. The only difference I know is I'm using Mono 3.2.5 and Ubuntu 13.04, also I'm using the master branch of XSP, mod_mono, and libgdiplus. I pulled the code through git.

**UPDATE**

I checked again the the current stable version of Mono and found out that it is 3.2.4 so I re-compiled it to this version but the the issue is still there.

**UPDATE 10-Dec 2013**
I was able to rebuild the server using Debian 7.0 and it is already running ASP.NET 4.0(and theoretically even 4.5). It can now run properly execute regular ASPX but not CSHTML.

The page runs properly under IIS on MS Windows 7 but it can't render and just download the page when I try to run it on mod_mono(mono 3.2.7 runtime) + Apache2 + Debian or XSP4 + Windows 7 though both can run ASPX pages properly. This test site still runs on my older server running mod_mono(mono 3.0.4 runtime) + Apache2 + Ubuntu 12.10. Both servers have the same configuration on both mod_mono.conf and site(/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default) but can't make it run on my new server.

Comment: do you have exactly the same configuration in the mod_mono.conf of Ubuntu 12.04? how did you install mono 3.2.5?

Comment: Yes, I have the same configuration on my new server from the old one.

I install it through Git, same as what I did on my older server.

Comment: how did you install mono? "through git" is not a very clear answer to this question

Comment: I followed the [Parallel Mono Environment Installation Instruction](http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments). I used "/opt/mono/3.2/" for my directory. But instead of using the compressed file, I just used this [instruction](http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_From_Git). Also I followed the other instructions for XSP and mod_mono from the official site.

After the installation, I just copied the same configuration as what is on my first server, including the directory structure.

Comment: what is what you refer as the `compressed file`? also, when installing XSP and mod_mono did you also use the prefix `/opt/mono/3.2`?

Comment: You can download mono source code through git or tar.gz(if I remember correctly), but I prefer the first one for minimal downloads every release.

And yeah, I used it. The same as I did with my first server.

Comment: ah, that is called a **tarball**

Comment: Yes, sorry for my ignorance but I still consider it as compressed files. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the following are already in the GAC, copying and placing the files in the "bin" directory fixed the issue:
System.Web.Helpers.dll
System.Web.Razor.dll
System.Web.WebPages.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll